# Custom Kafka Connector : Connector has errored out but Tasks are still running

Tags: apache-kafka, task, apache-kafka-connect, connector

I am building a Custom Kafka Source connector. This connector is up and running. I use the rest API to update the connector configuration settings (Source endpoint and connection key for instance). I use the below Rest API

`PUT /connectors/{name}/config`

Due to some issue the (wrong key for instance) the API does not succeed and the Connector fails

The API output is as below. Note that connector is in failed state, but the tasks are still running. In fact they are still 'connected' to the old endpoint and connection key instead of gracefully terminating the task.

```
{
    "name": "CustomSrcConnector_V1",
    "connector": {
        "state": "FAILED",
        "worker_id": "XXX.XX.XX.XX:8083",
        "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exception happened at Create : Exception in getPartitions()\n\tat com.xxx.yyy.kafka.connect.eventhub.CustomSourceConnector.start(CustomSourceConnector.java:102)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doStart(WorkerConnector.java:111)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.start(WorkerConnector.java:136)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.transitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:196)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startConnector(Worker.java:242)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startConnector(DistributedHerder.java:908)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.processConnectorConfigUpdates(DistributedHerder.java:345)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.tick(DistributedHerder.java:317)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.run(DistributedHerder.java:219)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\n"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "state": "RUNNING",
            "worker_id": "XXX.XX.XX.XX:8083"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "state": "RUNNING",
            "worker_id": "XXX.XX.XX.XX:8083"
        }
    ],
    "type": "source"
}
```

I understand that the tasks and connectors are generally decoupled. However i would like to know if there is any way of gracefully shutting down the tasks if the connector has errored out during the Conenctor configuration update.

Comment: It looks like a bug (similar to this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9639)

Comment: I agree. This is similar to the issue you pointe out. However there is no movement on that Jira issue since March 3 (6 weeks ago)

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no way to force fail tasks when the connector fails.

The solution I found so far is to catch any exceptions in the source connector and then instead of raising an exception in the source connector, allow the taskConfigs method run and reinitialize the tasks. We would need to allow the tasks to fail, so as a result we can have the connectors in RUNNING state, but the tasks as FAILED.
This will be in line with the example shared by  Iskuskov Alexander above

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9639